# Error: "Could not load file or assembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor"

Tags: c#, wcf, razor

Suddenly this problem has cropped up for no reason that I can understand.

My MVC application makes a call to a WCF Service. At that point it hits this exception. This was working yesterday. I can't think of anything relevant that changed, although it must be something. I can go back to previously working versions of this application, and now the error occurs.

Why is WebPages.Razor getting involved when trying to make a call to a WCF service? If I look at my References, there is a reference to System.Web.WebPages.Razor, and the location is valid. It looks like this DLL is managed by the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages nuget package ... why is it messed up? I have version 2.0.20710 of the package installed ... there are various places in web.config that reference System.Web.WebPages.Razor version 2.0.0.0.

My app crashes today, worked yesterday. Any ideas appreciated...

Here is an example of one of the web.config entries:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Following is the complete error message at the point the exception occurs:

System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '

```
<head>

    <title>Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <style>

     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 

     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }

     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }

     pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}

     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}

     .version {color: gray;}

     .error {margin-bottom: '.'
```

************************** update *****************************************

I've also noticed that I get the same error when I try to Update Service Reference on the WCF web service that is causing the problem. Somehow WebPages.Razor is attempting to load during the update operation, and failing.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: Yes, clean, rebuild, reboot, restart Visual Studio, update various packages like Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages, others,  ... many debugging techniques are underway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I have a separate class library to house my WCF services. This library had lost its installation of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Microsoft.AspNet.Razor and Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages. Once I reinstalled these nuget packages, the problem is resolved. They were already installed in the MVC client, of course. The biggest hurdle was that I could not figure out how Razor needed to be involved with my WCF services in a separate library / project from the MVC front-end. The error was very misleading.